# jQuery - delete element if exists body area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am using jQuery animate to change the position of multiple elements on the page (decorative elements). I want the element to be deleted if it exits `body` area. (if `left` is larger than `body width` or `top` is larger than `body height`).

The following can not be used in my case:

- overflow hidden for the body
- manually animating the element. I want to use jQuery animate to keep it simple (I dinamically create elements, animate them then I don't care about them, don't keep track of them, they have a .remove() methode when the animation is complete)

http://jsfiddle.net/a7Nck/

So in this JSfiddle I want the red div to dissappear when it reaches right edge of the `body` so that no scrollbars will appear.

Isn't there any CSS3 media query for example so that if a div is not in the viewport it will be hidden?

**EDIT:**

I just thought of a solution: get the width of the body prior to triggering the animation and then animate the `top` and `left` by using the minimum between the body size and what the animation should do. The problem is that this will affect animation speed.

Comment: There's no question here. This is not a site for code requests

Comment: I don't request code ... I ask for a solution for a problem I don't know how to solve myself. And the question is obvious... : "how to delete element if it exists body area?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use animate's `step` function.

> The second version of .animate() provides a step option — a callback function that is fired at each step of the animation. This function is useful for enabling custom animation types or altering the animation as it is occurring. It accepts two arguments (now and fx), and this is set to the DOM element being animated.

```
var w = $(window).width()
$('div').animate({
    left: '20px'
}, 500).delay(1000).animate({
    left: '2000px'
}, {
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if (now > w) {
            $(fx.elem).remove()
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7Nck/4/)

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround (assuming your first restriction is about globally adding `overflow: hidden` on your CSS): add `overflow: hidden` with js when the animation starts, and remove it when it ends:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
$('div').animate({left: '20px'},400).delay(1000).animate(
    {left: '2000px'},1000, false, function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7Nck/3/

Comment: I can't change body overflow as it will be a plug-in to be used on different websites so I must not alter in any way the look of that website. Anyway, clever solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the div when the last animation get completed i.e.

```
$('div').animate({left: '20px'},400).delay(1000).animate({left: '2000px'},1000, function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a7Nck/2/)

Comment: i think the point of the question is that he doesn't know whether or not it will be off the screen at the end of the animation.

Comment: @jbabey, in the question he clearly mentioned that "So in this JSfiddle I want the red div to dissappear when it reaches right edge of the body so that no scrollbars will appear." So i guess my answer is what he is expecting. Isn't it?

Comment: he's looking for a programatic and generic solution. this will work for that particular jsfiddle, but nothing else.

Comment: Scrollbars appear. I want NO scrollbars to appear, not for a millisecond.

Comment: I think @jbabey all other have given similar answer so i think you have understand the wrong meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the div leaves the visible area, the scrollbar will appear.  If you want to prevent the scrollbar from appearing, you can't allow the div to leave the screen.  Here's my solution:

```
$('div')
    .animate({left: '20px'},400)
    .delay(1000)
    .animate(
        {left: ($(window).width()-$('div').width()) + "px"},
        1000,
        null, // default easing
        function() { $('div').hide() }
    );
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4rdA/1/

​